# How to clear portion of a texture with alpha 0 using OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I have a texture onto which I render 16 drawings. The texture is 1024x1024 in size and it's divided into 4x4 "slots", each 256x256 pixels.

Before I render a new drawing into a slot, I want to clear it so that the old drawing is erased and the slot is totally transparent (alpha=0).

Is there a way to do it with OpenGL or need I just access the texture pixels directly in memory and clear them with memset oslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you'd just update the current texture normally:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> emptyPixels(1024*1024*4, 0); // Assuming RGBA / GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, yourTextureId);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                1024,
                1024,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                emptyPixels.data());  // Or &emptyPixels[0] if you're stuck with C++03
```

Even though you're replacing every pixel, [glTexSubImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml) is faster than recreating a new texture.

Comment: Thanks. Right after I had pressed "post" I thought about glTexSubImage2D as well :-) Silly me...

Answer (score 1):

Is your texture actively bound as a frame buffer target? (I'm assuming yes because you say you're rendering to it.)

If so, you can set a `glScissor` test, followed by a `glClear` to just clear a specific region of the framebuffer.

Comment: Wonder if that's faster or slower than glTexSubImage2D on iPhone 3Gs+? Most likely both methods are fast enough not to be significant...

Comment: Does glClear cause a flush? I thought it did, but I can't find a reference to back me up.  If it does, it could hurt performance.

Comment: @Mayoneez seems easy enough to try both ways and see for yourself :)